# Gulp and Coffeescript - signal async completion warning

Tags: configuration, gulp, coffeescript

### System configuration:

```
/gulp-demo$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2
/gulp-demo$ node -v
v12.4.0
/gulp-demo$ npm -v
6.14.1
```

### Project configuration

`package.json` configuration

```
{
  "name": "gulp-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffeescript": "^2.5.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-coffee": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-requirejs": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.7.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

`gulpfile.coffee` configuration:

```
gulp = require 'gulp'

gulp.task 'default', ->
    console.log 'Hello world!'
```

And nothing else.
Truing to execute gulp task:

```
/gulp-demo$ gulp
[03:09:58] Requiring external module coffeescript/register
[03:09:58] Using gulpfile ~/Development/projects/web/my/gulp-demo/gulpfile.coffee
[03:09:58] Starting 'default'...
Hello world!
[03:09:58] The following tasks did not complete: default
[03:09:58] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I understand that syntaxs is incorrect, verifying `coffeescript` documentation, it seems syntax correct.

I am new in `gulp` and `coffeescript` but I believe that something is missed there because of message.

### Question is:

How to resolve the issue?

```
[03:09:58] The following tasks did not complete: default
[03:09:58] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

### P.S.

Regarding message

```
[03:09:58] Requiring external module coffeescript/register
```

I tried to start it with parameter (to follow some recommendations), but result the same:

```
$ gulp --require coffeescript/register
```

### P.S.2.

If I try `gulp` from `gulpfile.js` file - everything is correct:

```
function defaultTask(cb) {
  console.log('Hello gulp!');
  cb();
}

exports.default = defaultTask
```

Console result is:

```
gulp-demo$ gulp
[03:44:40] Using gulpfile ~/Development/projects/web/my/gulp-demo/gulpfile.js
[03:44:40] Starting 'default'...
Hello gulp!
[03:44:40] Finished 'default' after 1.3 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gulp task](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gulp+task&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) must either be an `async` function or call the callback function when it is completed.

```
gulp.task 'default', (done) ->
  console.log 'Hello world!'
  done()
```

Or if you have any async functions you need to await, in coffeescript if a function contains `await`, it  will automatically become `async` as well. Then gulp will wait for it to be resolved. Example:

```
gulp.task 'default', () ->
  console.log 'Hello world!'
  await new Promise (resolve, reject) => 
    setTimeout 
        resolve() 
    , 1000
```